# How to read GZip content sent in a http response

Tags: curl, gzip, attachment, content-disposition, libcurl.net

I have been trying for over a week now to be able to read the gzipped content sent in an Http Respose.

OK, let me be more specific - the web server sends a response which has the Content-Disposition header and the attachment attribute, like under,

Content-Disposition: attachment, filename=00011122.txt

I can save all the "response headers" that come to me, however am unable to save the .txt file that is sent. Moreover, after all the headers are recevied, I also received some gibberish text, which I assume is the .txt file.

But I have absolutely no clue how I can save this file and decompress it and view the contents as any other text file.

I have searched the internet and tried many things, but nothing seems to help.

I am using cURL - libcurl.net, C# as my programming languages.

Any help, suggestion, feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jay

Comment: What specifically does this have to do with Content-Disposition?

Anyway, what you probably see is a response using *Content-Encoding* "gzip". So what you need to do is to apply GZIP uncompression to the payload.

Answer (score 0):

The support is yet to be added to cURL. See: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/tracker-2007-12/0008.html

Comment: Thanks Kedar for your response. I had read that earlier but was hoping that this functionality is now added to cURL.

Would you know how one can achieve downloading of the file sent as part of the Content-Disposition header?

Fiddler does it very well and shows the contents of the file accurately. Any idea how this is done and can be achieved?

Comment: IMO, you can easily write a simple client that reads the Content-Disposition header and save the contents (that are sent by the server as the file/attachment) locally. It's just that cURL right now does not have support for that. Note that the server is supposed to send the file as part of the response body.

Answer (score 0):

I wish it was as easy as you mentioned. Unfortunately, it cannot be done that easily. Especially when the content is gzip'd.

I have come across quite a few examples on the internet that save data from a response. However, not a single example that shows how to save data that is sent as part of the Content-Dispositon header and especially when the content is gzip'd.

Do kindly let me know if you know how to do this.

Regards,
Jay